# Understanding `decEq`

Tags: equality, idris

Given:

```
*section3> :module Data.Vect    
*section3> :let e  = the (Vect 0 Int) []
*section3> :let xs = the (Vect _ _) [1,2]

*section3> decEq xs e
(input):1:7:When checking argument x2 to function Decidable.Equality.decEq:
        Type mismatch between
                Vect 0 Int (Type of e)
        and
                Vect 2 Integer (Expected type)

        Specifically:
                Type mismatch between
                        0
                and
                        2
```

Why must the `Nat` arguments equal each other for DecEq?

Note - posted in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/idris-lang/qgtImCLka3I originally

Comment: `Vect 0 Int` and `Vect 1 Int` are different types just like `Vect n Int` and `Vect n Float` are.

Answer (score 4):

[`decEq`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/0d3d2d66796b172e9933360aee51993a4abc624d/libs/prelude/Decidable/Equality.idr#L27) is for **homogenous** propositional equality:

```
||| Decision procedures for propositional equality
interface DecEq t where
  ||| Decide whether two elements of `t` are propositionally equal
  total decEq : (x1 : t) -> (x2 : t) -> Dec (x1 = x2)
```

As you can see, `x1` and `x2` are both of type `t`. In your case, you have `x1 : Vect 2 Integer` and `x2 : Vect 0 Int`. These are two different types.

You can write your own heterogenous equality decider for `Vect`ors of the same element type by first checking their lengths, then delegating to the homogenous version:

```
import Data.Vect

vectLength : {xs : Vect n a} -> {ys : Vect m a} -> xs = ys -> n = m
vectLength {n = n} {m = n} Refl = Refl

decEqVect : (DecEq a) => (xs : Vect n a) -> (ys : Vect m a) -> Dec (xs = ys)
decEqVect {n = n} {m = m} xs ys with (decEq n m)
 decEqVect xs ys | Yes Refl = decEq xs ys
 decEqVect xs ys | No notEq = No (notEq . vectLength)
```